# How to convert IF or nested If statement like EXCEL to dynamic SQL Query in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have came across one pretty problem in which I need to convert the nested if statement (like we used to write in excel) to dynamic SQL query.

I want to convert this

```
select 'IIF(A>B,A,IIF(B>C,B,C))'
```

to like this

```
select 'CASE WHEN A>B THEN A ELSE CASE WHEN B > C THEN B ELSE C END END'.
```

Why I am doing this I have formula column in the table user can insert formula in that and I need to convert this to SQL statement.
Do anyone has idea how can I do that?

The above is for only example I will be having 150 rows for different formula's entered by user.

Note : Here do not interpret `IIF` as SQL server `IIF`, it can be IF.

Comment: `IIF` is supported syntax in T-SQL (not sure about SQL 2008 though)

Comment: Not *IIF* not supported in SQL. 
I am using this IIF to take input from user so that non-technical can insert the value.

Comment: Obligatory note that SQL Server 2008 has been **completely** unsupported for almost 3 years; it is long past time you upgraded.

Comment: To confirm, `IIF` was added in SQL Server 2012; so the problem would not exist if the OP were using a supported version of SQL Server, @Nick.McDermaid .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that A,B,C are numbers we can do something like this

```
SELECT 
  (
   Select MAX(cols) 
   from 
   (VALUES (ColA), (ColB), (ColC))tbl(cols)
   ) as greatest
from yourtable
```

Comment: thanks dhruv for comment, how about solving this Select 'IIF(([SER1]) *  [EDU2] * 0.01>10,([BED001]) * 0.01 *   [CESS],([Basic Amount] - [DISC01]) *  [TDS]  * 0.01)'.  User can enter N number of combination using the heads.